# Entity Framework: LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

Tags: linq, entity-framework

The following query used to run without issues, until a recent update (latest asp.net web application using framework 4.5 instead of 4. EF version 6 didn't change).

```
var criteria = (from c in context.CruiseCalendar
                        where c.ShipId == sourceId
                        && c.CruiseDayDate >= dateRange.Start
                        && c.CruiseDayDate <= dateRange.End
                        select new 
                        {
                            Date = c.CruiseDayDate,
                            DestinationId = c.ListingId
                        });

        var rendezvous = (from r in context.CruiseCalendar
                            where (criteria.Any(d => d.Date == r.CruiseDayDate
                            && d.DestinationId == r.ListingId))
                            select r).GroupBy(x => x.CruiseDayDate)  
                            .Where(x => x.Count() >= shipCount)  
                            .SelectMany(x => x)
                            .OrderBy(r => r.CruiseDayDate)
                            .ToList();
```

Now I get the error as noted in the title. I've tried attaching a .ToList() to the 'criteria' query, which yields a different exception: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Is there something wrong in the way I'm trying to query the data? Is there an alternative approach which circumnavigates the need to a) generate a collection of anonymous objects and b) run a query based on these criteria? (I had this down pat in SQL but am trying to avoid that with a pure EF/Linq approach).

By the way, if it's not clear what I'm trying to achieve here's some test data: (for ease of reading I've used ShipName and PortName instead of shipID and PortId

```
CruiseDayDate  /  ShipName     / PortName

01/July/2014,   Nostromo,   Miami

01/July/2014,   Potemkin,   Miami

01/July/2014,   Titanic,    San Juan

02/July/2014,   Nostromo,   Freeport

02/July/2014,   Potemkin,   Labadee

02/July/2014,   Titanic,    Freeport
```

Using Nostromo as an input parameter, the first query finds out where this ship will be, and when. (1 July Miami, 2nd July Freeport)
The second query finds out which other ships the Nostromo will 'rendezvous' with. ie  1st July with the Potemkin (Miami), and 2nd July with the Titanic (Freeport).

```
02/July/2014    Titanic, Freeport
```

Comment: What is dateRange? Also, what are the types of its `Start` and `End` properties?

Comment: Example: dateRange.Start = 1/July/2015. dateRange.End = 8/July/2015. Search for 'rendezvous'which fall between 1 and 8 July, 2015.